# How do I play with Lynda etc. Postgres example files on MAMP without screwing up my current local environment? (beginner here)

Tags: database, postgresql, localhost, mamp-pro

So my company installed PostgreSQL on my computer, which I use, rarely and without understanding, for one specific function.

I'm trying to follow Lynda etc. tutorials to understand (Postgres)SQL better, since that's what we use, but all the tutorials ask students to reconfigure certain aspects of their system in order to follow along with example files (which I would really like to do).

Since I've messed up my dev env once already, I'm hesitant to touch anything that will cause issues with the local versions of our project.

I know this is an extremely wide-angle question with no easy answer, but if anyone has any general advice for playing with sample databases in MAMP Pro (or anywhere else) using Postgres without interfering with the servers I'm currently running, it would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you use Vagrant and set up a isolated postgresql instance. [Here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_For_Development_With_Vagrant) is a great wiki you can follow to do this.

UPDATE: Given your comment,An easy solution is to just backup your data and proceed trying out the the Postgres examples you can always restore your data after you are done..

Comment: I did attempt to do that, but clearly was out of my depth.  The real answer should have been:
1. Backup your system
2. Proceed